# Problem linking datagrid to text Input

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, datagrid, textinput

What I am trying to do is have a user input his data into multiple textboxes, then once the data is entered it is displayed on the datagrid at runtime. The problem is when I run the app I click my button but no information entered is added to datagrid. My textboxes are also supposed to clear once the button is pressed but again nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

     import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

     [Bindable]private var dgItems:ArrayCollection;
     [Bindable]public var temp:Object;


     public function addItem(evt:Event):void {
     //add item if the text input fields are not empty
      if(name_input.text != ""&& location_input.text !="") {
     //create a temporary Object
      temp = myDG.selectedItem;
      var temp:Object = new Object();
     //add the text from the textfields to the object
      temp = {name:name_input.text, location:location_input.text};

     //this will add the object to the ArrayColldection (wich is binded with the DataGrid)
      dgItems.addItem(temp);
     //clear the input fields
      name_input.text = "";
       location_input.text ="";
      }
     }
    ]]>
   </mx:Script>

 <mx:DataGrid  x="97" y="110"  dataProvider="{dgItems}" id="myDG">
  <mx:columns>
   <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 1" dataField="name:"/>
   <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 2" dataField="location:"/>

  </mx:columns>
 </mx:DataGrid>
 <mx:Button x="97" y="51" label="add" click="addItem(event)"/>
 <mx:TextInput x="117" y="300" id="location_input"/>
 <mx:TextInput x="117" y="340" id="name_input"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you having a problem?  If so, please tell us what the problem is so we know what issues we're looking for in your code.

Comment: The problem is when I hit my button to add the user inputted data nothing happens. Nothing is added to the grid nor are the input boxes cleared. That leaves me to think maybe there's click event problem with my button but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has lots of errors.  First, you were not initializing the dgItems array collection, so it's value was null.  You would get errors when you tried to "addItem" to the null object.

Second you were trying to access the selectedItem of the dataGrid before initializing the DataGrid's ArrayCollection dataProvider.  No items in the list, there can be no selectedItem.

Third, you're creating the new object twice; once with the 'new Object' line and again with
the in-line syntax for defining ojects: '{}

Fourth, the datafield properties on the DataGridColumn both had colons in them, but the object's properties did not.

I hope this helps.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            // array collection was never initialized; you can't items to a null object 
            [Bindable]private var dgItems:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
// not needed
//          [Bindable]public var temp:Object;


            public function addItem(evt:Event):void {
                //add item if the text input fields are not empty
                if(name_input.text != ""&& location_input.text !="") {
                    //create a temporary Object
                    // this line of code serves no purpos
                    //                  temp = myDG.selectedItem;
                    var temp:Object // = new Object();
                    //add the text from the textfields to the object
                    temp = {name:name_input.text, location:location_input.text};

                    //this will add the object to the ArrayColldection (wich is binded with the DataGrid)
                    dgItems.addItem(temp);
                    //clear the input fields
                    name_input.text = "";
                    location_input.text ="";
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:DataGrid  x="97" y="110"  dataProvider="{dgItems}" id="myDG">
        <mx:columns>
            <!-- need to remove the colons from the data field -->
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 1" dataField="name"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 2" dataField="location"/>

        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
    <mx:Button x="97" y="51" label="add" click="addItem(event)"/>
    <mx:TextInput x="117" y="300" id="location_input"/>
    <mx:TextInput x="117" y="340" id="name_input"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Many of these errors were easy to catch as soon as I launched the debugger.  If you aren't already using it, I suggest doing some reading up on it.

Comment: Thank you for the above help but once I made the improvements to my code it still doesnt work. Its still not sending my input into the datagrid once my button is clicked. Here's an example of what I need it to do: Lets say the user is inputting the name and location of his clients into text input, after he clicks the submit button his input is saved to the datagrid. If you could give a few pointers on how to do that I would appreciate it.

Comment: The code I posted was doing just what you describe.  Here is a link: 
http://www.flextras.com/labs/forlou/DataGridUpdate_SO.html
And the source http://www.flextras.com/labs/forlou/srcview/

Comment: My mistake, Im fairly new to programming so Im still trying to wrap my head around these concepts. Anyways, problem solved. You got my day off to a good start. Much Thanks.